# neo4j cypher how to find the most frequent pattern of nodes in a chain of word-nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a GraphDB with Texts as a chain of word-nodes.

a small Test-Query looks like this:

```
MATCH p=(n1:Token)-[:NEXT_TOKEN]->(n2:Token)-[:NEXT_TOKEN]->(n3:Token)  
WHERE n1.text = 'von'
AND n2.text = 'den'
RETURN n1.text, n2.text, n3.text, 
count(p) AS n3Anzahl ORDER BY n3Anzahl DESC;
```

What i need is a list of the 3-Word-Chains with the most frequent on top.

Any ideas would be helpfull.

Comment: We don't have credentials to access your db, and not a great idea to make your db publicly available unless you've restricted it to read-only.

Comment: The query itself looks like it should do what you want. In what way is it not working for you?

Comment: I want to create this query for every possible combination. I try to make the DB public and read_only.

Comment: Okay, so take out your WHERE clause and the query should work.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Falcon:
Okay, so take out your WHERE clause and the query should work